# I am creating snooze for android alarm but i can't make it out?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am creating android alarm aap in which while adding snooze button to alarm i am getting an error what i can't understand any one can help me?

```
buttonSnooze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_snooze);
        buttonSnooze.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
                  PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                      PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                  long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                  long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + 5 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
                  Time nextUpdateTime = new Time();
                  nextUpdateTime.set(nextUpdateTimeMillis);

                  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pendingIntent);
            }
            });
```

and the error is as follows
The method getService(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, Intent, int)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are using `onTouch` at `setOnClickListener`

what you need to do is :

try to write code as below

```
Button buttonSnooze = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_snooze);
    snooze.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
             mMediaPlayer.stop();
             finish();
             return true;
        }
};
```

Then before where you call the alarm, update the time

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + 5 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
Time nextUpdateTime = new Time();
nextUpdateTime.set(nextUpdateTimeMillis);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i had edited the code above please check and answer

Comment: getting error at .getService method in pendingIntent can you show other way to solve it.